# Sorting Query for SQL

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

How can we achieve the following sorting order using a query in SQL?

```
Title_a
Title_b
Title_c
Title_d
Title_1a
Title_1b
Title_1c
Title_1d
Title_11a
Title_11b
Title_11c
Title_111a
Title_111b
Title_111c
Title_111d
Title_1111a
Title_1112a
Title_1112b
Title_12a
Title_12b
Title_12c
Title_1311a
Title_1311b
Title_1311c
Title_1311d
```

I have tried String sort="`CAST ("+ "title" + " AS INTEGER)`";
but the results are not satisfying

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: lower your expectations then results should be satisfying ... seriously, where is the question and what is the problem?

Comment: Is this really what your data looks like or is it "sample" data?

What you could do is the split as you've mentioned in your question and then take the chr() value of the last letter and add that to the integer value of everything before the last letter?

Comment: @JonTout this is how the exact sorting should work and basically I am an android developer but need to sort such results using a SQL query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff this is actually an android application where you need to query a list with sorting as above from SQL DB.

Comment: @Abhilash so what I'd do is "ignore" the "Title_" part of the string, sum the total of the numbers and add that to the chr() value of the final letter and that *should* work. I'll see if I can knock something together

Comment: Is the DBMS perhaps SqLite? Which version?

Comment: @LukStorms it is 3.19 (in Android pie )

Comment: @LukStorms, thanks mate while some can't even know where the question and how the answer would be :p you got it very serious :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those strings it would order fine if it weren't for that last character.

So for those strings you could order by what's before the last character, then the last character.

```
select *
from yourtable
order by substr(title,1,length(title)-1), substr(title,length(title),1)
```

Comment: Thanks, mate :) That was a piece of cake :)

Comment: Thx. Btw, if you have control over the naming of those titles. Then it might be a nice idea to add that number with padded zero's. So that it's the same amount of digits in them. Then they could simply be orded by title.

Comment: Yes, That would be even faster. But our requirements are deadly like this and they call it user-oriented / user-friendly :p

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment, "Title_1311b" the value 1311 is added to the ASCII value of "b".

```
Declare @col varchar(15)  = 'Title_1311b'


SELECT SUBSTRING(@col, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @col), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', @col) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @col) + 1)  +  ascii(right(@col,1))+1
```

Can you add this to your sql query and see what happens?

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(@col, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @col), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', @col) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @col) + 1)  +  ascii(right(@col,1))+1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot JonTout, LukStroms got me there :)

Comment: Thanks, no worry - I agree with padding recommendation above